# Как сделать чтобы при обновлении страницы форма не отправлялась заного?

Tags: php, sms

```
введите сюда код      Обратная сзязь ,Оставте ваш номер<br> телефона и мы вам перезвоним<br>
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['but']) ) {
    require_once 'sms.ru.php';
    $smsru = new SMSRU('C3A6B841-6B90-4FD6-4ED5-B4FFB841F914'); // Ваш уникальный программный ключ, который можно получить на главной странице
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $num = trim($_POST['num']);
    $text = trim($_POST['text']);

    if(empty($name)){
        echo "Поле имя пусто. ";
        /*Выход или редирект*/
    }

    if(empty($num)){
        echo "Поле номер пусто. ";
        /*Выход или редирект*/
    }

    if(empty($text)){
        echo "Поле заказ  пусто. ";
        /*Выход или редирект*/
    }



    if(!empty($name) && !empty($num) && !empty($text) ){

        $data = new stdClass();
        $data->to = '89065906733';
        $data->text = $name . "-" . $num . "-" . $text; // Текст сообщения

        $sms = $smsru->send_one($data);// Отправка сообщения и возврат данных в переменную


        if ($sms->status == "OK") { // Запрос выполнен успешно
            echo "Сообщение отправлено успешно. ";
            echo "Ваш новый баланс: $sms->balance";
        } else {
            echo "Сообщение не отправлено. ";
            echo "Код ошибки: $sms->status_code. ";
            echo "Текст ошибки: $sms->status_text.";
            echo $form;
        }
    }
```

P.s html и php в ондом файле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновление страницы вызывает повторную отправку последнего запроса, форма отправляется потому что последний запрос был POST, чтобы это избежать после успешной обработки POST запроса надо сделать редирект. Тут есть подробности https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: я погуглил и написано что можно сделать редирект в отдельном файле ток как я не знаю и как этот файл подключить <?php

header («Location: localhost/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0/index.php»);



?> вот такой код по идее только как его подключить и активировать?

Comment: if ($sms->status == "OK") { // Запрос выполнен успешно
    header («Location: url);
}

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($sms->status == "OK") { // Запрос выполнен успешно
    echo "Сообщение отправлено успешно. "; // показываем пользователю сообщение
    echo "Ваш новый баланс: $sms->balance";
    sleep(10); //ждём 10 секунд
    header('Location: http://google.ru'); //отправляем куда надо
    exit;
}
```

Можно через JS:

```
if ($sms->status == "OK") { // Запрос выполнен успешно
    echo "Сообщение отправлено успешно. "; // показываем пользователю сообщение
    echo "Ваш новый баланс: $sms->balance";
    echo "<script language = 'javascript'>
    var delay = 10000; //время в мс.
    setTimeout(\"document.location.href='http://google.ru'\", delay);
    </script>";
}
```